# How to use XPath `(//path)[n]` syntax in MySQL's ExtractValue

Tags: mysql, xpath

I am trying to get the value of the second instance of a specified tag appearing at any part of an XML structure, using MySQL (5.7).

An example XML extract is:

```
SET @xml = '
<root>
    <lang>English</lang>
    <lang>French</lang>
    <section>
        <lang>German</lang>
        <lang>Bulgarian</lang>
    </section>
</root>
';
```

I would normally use the XPath `(//lang)[2]`, which should in this case obtain 'French', but this is not working in MySQL:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '(//lang)[2]');

-- Result should be: "French"
-- but server response is instead:
-- "#1105 - XPATH syntax error: '[2]'"
```

A similar syntax, which is not what is wanted, does compile, but obviously gives the unwanted result:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '//lang[2]');

-- Result, which is not what is wanted, is: "French Bulgarian"
```

Note that the  value may appear anywhere in the structure. I am trying to find e.g. the second instance anywhere.

Does MySQL actually support the `(//path)[n]` syntax? I believe this is XPath 1.0, which MySQL supposedly supports.